# What are the valid values for "band" in a GeoTiff file?

Tags: geotiff-tiff

What are the valid values for "band" in a GeoTiff file?

I've looked through the Geotiff Spec at http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/spec/geotiffhome.html and I am having trouble finding information about multi-band imagery.

I'm looking for documentation that answers these questions:

- Do the band values always start at 1?
- Is band 0 a valid band?
- What is the max band allowed?

I am looking at the Band information that is reported from running gdalinfo on a geotiff file.

Comment: Are you worried about limits on the number of bands? Do you perhaps want a multidimensional array (say NetCDF or HDF format) rather than a GeoTIFF? Multiple bands are sometimes used to stored an "unrolled" array in a 2d raster (this is how GDAL will represent NetCDF/HDF and others), but it's not exactly ideal. You might want multiple attributes on a multidimensional array, and GIS formats are not generally suited to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean the maximum number of bands? I don't think 0 is acceptable, simply by convention on the method GDAL uses to access bands.

The type for nBandId is int, so that would suggest that you could have about 2 billion bands in GDAL, but I'm not sure if GeoTIFF allows that as well.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180716155258/http://www.gdal.org:80/classGDALDataset.html#d96adcf07f2979ad176e37a7f8638fb6)

Comment: I created a 40K band GeoTIFF with rgdal, so I know at least it's not limited to 32768 :)